# Notation for the subcategory of commutative $R$-algebras

Tags: notation, category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (with identity) and let $R\mathbf{Alg}$
denote the category of $R$-algebras.

My question:

> Is there a suitable
>   notation for the full subcategory of **commutative** $R$-algebras?

I would like to know this in order to classify the polynomial ring
$R\left[S\right]$ - where $S$ is a set - as an object of category
? free over set $S$.

In the special case $R=\mathbb{Z}$ the notation $\mathbf{CRing}$ will do,
since rings can be recognized as $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. But what
in the general case?

Comment: I've never seen a notation for it; use whatever conveys the idea: $\mathbf{CAlg}_R$, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will practicize it if nothing else shows up. Just like you I never saw a notation either (hence my question). Peculiar. Maybe guys like Zhen Lin or Martin Brandenburg have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen the notation $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$ in many places. I prefer $\mathsf{CAlg}(R)$ in order to stress the functoriality. This is also used in Yves Diers' work. Many papers restrict to commutative rings and algebras in the first place and therefore just write $\mathsf{Alg}_R$ (which might be confusing - but this is just a local notation).

More generally, if $C$ is a symmetric monoidal category, then I've seen $\mathsf{CAlg}(C)$, $\mathsf{CMon}(C)$ and $\mathsf{Comm}(C)$ for the category of commutative algebras in $C$. For $C=\mathsf{Mod}(R)$ one often abbreviates $?(\mathsf{Mod}(R))$ with $?(R)$, so that you would write $\mathsf{CAlg}(R)$ or $\mathsf{Comm}(R)$ for the category of commutative $R$-algebras.

As for the font, instead of $\mathsf{CAlg}$ of course you can also write $\mathrm{CAlg}$ or $\mathbf{CAlg}$. This is not standard (as for module categories).

Comment: Thank you. Und gratuliert noch (WK 2014)! This time I am very satisfied with our achievements. In 1974 ): that was different.

Comment: What does WK mean?

Comment: Wereldkampioenschap (Weltmeisterschaft). Have a look at http://nos.nl/wk2014/artikel/671700-1974-waarom-wonnen-de-duitsers.html